# Error with autoloader after using migration tool

Tags: laravel, composer-php, autoload

I'm using the artisan tool in order to manage my DB schema. My project is developped with the Laravel framework and a SQLite DB.

Yesterday I've tried to delete one of my migrations.
I used the command : `artisan migrate:reset` then I deleted the file in the migrations folder.
Since that time I get this error before Laravel loading :

```
    Fatal error: Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInit0c92428cc11919ebbe745ec1a91c61b1' not found in /mypath/vendor/autoload.php on line 7
```

I've try the dump-autoload command but no results. I've also updated my project with composer.

Any idea ? It's not the first time I get this error. But this one I don't succeed in resolving it. Is there something I don't understand or do correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it was a synchronization misconfiguration with the server and my IDE Netbean. I have to disable the use of temporary files on your project and/or to force the synchronization.

Comment: thx, this helped me out +1! I didn't know how to disable the use of temporary files, so I just closed and reopened my project and it worked.